# How can I select the H1 tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to target the first or last h1 tag **without using CSS nth selector**; how can I do this?

```
<div>
  <p> 1st P</p>
  <h1> First H1</h1>
  <h1> Second H1</h1>
  <h1> Third H1</h1>
  <p> 2nd P</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) pseudo-classes.

```css
h1:first-of-type {
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

h1:last-of-type {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> 1st P</p>
  <h1> First H1</h1>
  <h1> Second H1</h1>
  <h1> Third H1</h1>
  <p> 2nd P</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @TouhidRahman please select the answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS element+element Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

**Remember, the `element+element` selector is used to select elements that are placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.**

```css
div p + h1,
div p + h1 + h1 + h1{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> 1st P</p>
  <h1> First H1</h1>
  <h1> Second H1</h1>
  <h1> Third H1</h1>
  <p> 2nd P</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't work with the provided markup as `<p>` is the first and last element of the parent `<div>`.

Comment: Does not work... As <p> tag comes before & after <h1> tags

Comment: @Siraj while this technically works, it's virtually the same difference as `nth-child`. Meaning, less flexible. It requires you to have fixed locations of the first and last `h1`. Given that the OP has not stated that there could be a variable amount of `h1` or that there could be any number of elements before the first `h1`, this is a _"somewhat"_ acceptable solution.

Comment: Its very rigid code Siraj. We can't use if there are more children elements and inserting new children will also break the styling.

We should always go with maintainable coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can give class name your last tag and with his you can turn to him

```html
<div>
  <p> 1st P</p>
  <h1> First H1</h1>
  <h1> Second H1</h1>
  <h1 class="yourClass"> Third H1</h1>
  <p> 2nd P</p>
</div>
```